# RadDataForm Multiple select in nativescript-vue

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

I have this TKEntityProperty:

```
    <TKEntityProperty v-tkDataFormProperty name="groups" displayName="Groups" index="2" :valuesProvider="retrieveGroups">
```

and this gets values from below object:

```
retrieveGroups:[
   {key: "1", "label": "Group 1"},
   {key: "2", "label": "Group 2"},
   {key: "3", "label": "Group 3"} 
]
```

but it does not multi select. I want to select multiple elements.
Is there another type of editor available ?

Comment: "List" editor doesn't support picking multiple items. Use AutoCompleteInline or you will have to introduce a custom editor of your own.

Comment: example with AutoCompleteInline?

Comment: You just have to refer the [docs](https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/ui/professional-ui-components/ng-DataForm/Editors/dataform-editors-list)

Answer (score 0):

As @Manoj suggested, you should use [AutoCompleteInline](https://docs.nativescript.org/ns-ui-api-reference/enums/dataformeditortype#autocompleteinline)
Here is an example, it is available at Nativescript [github](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-ui-samples-vue/blob/master/dataform/app/examples/Autocomplete.ts) page

```
data() {
  return {
    title: description,
    booking: new Booking(),
    bookingMetadata: {
      'isReadOnly': false,
      'commitMode': DataFormCommitMode.Immediate,
      'validationMode': DataFormValidationMode.Immediate,
      'propertyAnnotations': [{
          'name': 'from',
          'displayName': 'From:',
          'index': 0,
          'editor': DataFormEditorType.AutoCompleteInline,
          'editorParams': {
            'autoCompleteDisplayMode': AutoCompleteDisplayMode.Tokens
          },
          'valuesProvider': fromProviders,
        },
        {
          'name': 'to',
          'displayName': 'To:',
          'index': 1,
          'editor': DataFormEditorType.AutoCompleteInline,
          'editorParams': {
            'autoCompleteDisplayMode': AutoCompleteDisplayMode.Plain
          },
          'valuesProvider': ['New York', 'Washington', 'Los Angeles'],
        },
      ]
    }
  };
},
```

Comment: ok, but when select one item in list, this not disappear from list. I want select only one time for item. And have noticed not return an array of data in editedObejct